# Referring to two or many corollaries in LateX

Tags: cleveref, amsthm, newtheorem

I am using `\thref{cor1, cor2}` to cite two corollaries, and it provides [image: ![this output] instead of Corollaries 3.3.9 and 3.3.10. (It gives "Corollarys" as the plural of Corrolary).

If I have the following lines in my .tex document:

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{corollary}\thlabel{cor1}
First corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}\thlabel{cor2}
Second corollary
\end{corollary}

Now, I am citing \thref{cor1,cor2}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: this]:

Could anyone help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please never post fragments of LaTeX code. Provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that people can copy-paste and test. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Miyase. I have just edited the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't use `theoremref` and rely on `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{theoremref}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{corollary}\label{cor1}
First corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}\label{cor2}
Second corollary
\end{corollary}

Now, I am citing \cref{cor1,cor2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to include `\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{corollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}` so that, as your original suggested you wanted, you get the names to begin with upper-case letters.

Comment: @murray Or simply use `\Cref`. I don't like too many uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works now. I just wondef if `theoremref` has this functionality.

Comment: @DimbiRabearivony As far as I can see from the code, the answer is no. To the contrary, `cleveref` can be heavily customized.